# Python: Replace every 5th value of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy array full of floats. How can I replace every 5th value with `np.inf*0` so that I get a `NaN` value at every 5th index?

```
my_array = np.array([5.0, 8.1, 3.2, 2.7, 8.4, 4.9 ...])
```

to

```
my_array = np.array([5.0, 8.1, 3.2, 2.7, NaN, 4.9 ...])
```

and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using slicing and striding? `L[::5]` takes every 5th element from list `L`:

```
>>> my_array = np.arange(20.)
>>> my_array[4::5] = np.nan
>>> my_array
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,  nan,  10.,
        11.,  12.,  13.,  nan,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  nan])
```

Comment: he wants to change `my_array[4::5]`

Comment: @stranac: ah good point, didn't catch that he wanted to skip the first four. Updated.

Comment: Use `np.arange(20.)` instead of `np.array(range(20))` to avoid the creation of an intermediate list and to make the values actually `nan` instead of `-9223372036854775808`.  The `.` is to make the dtype float (or `np.arange(20, float)`, since `np.nan` doesn't exist as an integer (as can be seen in your output).

Comment: @askewchan: great comment, thanks, it really cleans up the answer and the output.

Comment: You can still remove the first `np.array` call: `my_array = np.arange(20.)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler than @alko's and <strike>more correct than @mdml's</strike>.

```
import numpy

my_array = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 20)
my_array
#>>> array([ 0.        ,  0.05263158,  0.10526316,  0.15789474,  0.21052632,
#>>>         0.26315789,  0.31578947,  0.36842105,  0.42105263,  0.47368421,
#>>>         0.52631579,  0.57894737,  0.63157895,  0.68421053,  0.73684211,
#>>>         0.78947368,  0.84210526,  0.89473684,  0.94736842,  1.        ])

my_array[4::5] = numpy.nan
my_array
#>>> array([ 0.        ,  0.05263158,  0.10526316,  0.15789474,         nan,
#>>>         0.26315789,  0.31578947,  0.36842105,  0.42105263,         nan,
#>>>         0.52631579,  0.57894737,  0.63157895,  0.68421053,         nan,
#>>>         0.78947368,  0.84210526,  0.89473684,  0.94736842,         nan])
```

Comment: This is still more correct than @mdml's answer because the array dtype is float, and thus `np.nan` is conserved.